# Gsuite Directory API 403 Error on API call or Grant Type Error on JWT Generation

Tags: jwt, google-workspace

Using Python and creating my own JWT using HTTP/Rest methodology, I simply can't get delegation to work.

On one hand, google JWT troubleshoot documentation says that ISS needs to be the same as the SUB (the service account).

However, on the server to server oauth2 documentation, it says that to impersonate an account, the sub needs to be the account I am attempting to impersonate in the claim.

Needless to say, despite enabling domain-wide delegation, adding the correct scopes, etc, I get nothing back but 403 when attempting to access the user domain utilizing the requests library in python with the following example:

```
> requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/useremail@/
> google.org",headers={'Authorization':f' Bearer {oauth2tokenhere}'})
```

Here is an example of my claim:

```
> claim = { "iss": 'serviceaccountemail', 
>         'sub': 'impersonatedaccountemail',
>         'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
>         'exp': ((datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)).timestamp()),
>         'iat': ((datetime.datetime.today()).timestamp()),
>         'aud': "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
>     }
```

The above claim will generate a generalized grant error (cute, but not helpful).

If I change the claim and ensure that the sub and the iss are the same, the oauth2token generates, but I get a 403 error when attempting to hit the API.

Here is the server to server oauth2 documentation stating the sub should be the
account the service account is attempting to impersonate.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Here is the troubleshooting article outlining the ISS/Sub being the same (although cloud article is the closest relevant topic I could find)

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-jwt

EDIT:

I am utilizing the service account information from the downloaded .json file that is downloaded when creating the service account file.

```
import json as j
import datetime
import jwt
import requests



#creates the claim, 'secret' (from the private key), and the kid, from the service account file, and returns these values in a tuple.
#the tuple can then be used to make dependable positional argument entries to the parameters of the createJWT function.

def create_claim_from_json(self,objpath,scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly" "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"]):

    with open(f'{objpath}','r') as jobj:
        data = j.load(jobj)

    claim = {
        "iss": str(data['client_id']),
        "sub": str(data['client_id']),
        "scope": str(scope),
        "exp": ((datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=59)).timestamp()),
        "iat": ((datetime.datetime.today()).timestamp()),
        "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    }

    private_key = data['private_key']

    kid = {"kid": f"{data['private_key_id']}"}

    return claim, private_key, kid


#assembles the JWT using the claim, secret (Private key from the Service account file), the kid value, and the documented RS256 alg.
#returns the completed JWT object back to be used to send to the oauth2 endpoint
#the JWT will be used in the function call retrieve_oauth2token.

def createJWT(self, claim, secret, kid, alg='RS256'):

    encoded_jwt = (jwt.encode(claim, secret, alg, kid)).decode('UTF-8')

    return encoded_jwt


#Using the JWT created in memory, sends the JWT to the googleapi oauth2 uri and returns a token

def retrieve_oauth2token(self, jwt):

    oauth2 = requests.post(f'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-    type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion={jwt}')

    oauth2=oauth2.json()

    return oauth2 #['access_token'], oauth2['token_type']
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) has a clear overview, did you follow the steps as described in the addendum? I am missing some parts of your code. But you did not mention using a service account (json) key. And the documentation also show that you have to use the (delegated) service account as both iss and sub. Furthermore, you need to use a kid. This is how it is done:

```
payload = {
    'iss': '123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    'sub': '123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    'aud': 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/',
    'iat': time.time(),
    'exp': iat + 3600
}
additional_headers = {'kid': PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON}
signed_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON, headers=additional_headers, algorithm='RS256')

url = "URL OF THE API TO CALL"
header = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {signed_jwt}'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

Note: you can find `PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON` in the private_key_id field of your service account JSON credentials file.

Comment: I'll have to verify if the Directory API / AdminSDK can be accessed though JWT alone.

I'll edit my original post to include the function calls I created to handle the JWT.